# Creating a pandas column conditional to another columns values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to create a class column in a pandas dataframe conditional another columns values. The value will be 1 if the other column's i+1 value is greater than the i value and 0 otherwise.

For example:

```
column1 column2
   5       1
   6       0
   3       0
   2       1
   4       0
```

How do create column2 by iterating through column1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `diff` method on the first column with a period of `-1`, then check if it is less than zero to create the second column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1': [5,6,3,2,4]})
df['c2'] = (df.c1.diff(-1) < 0).astype(int)

df
# returns:
   c1  c2
0   5   1
1   6   0
2   3   0
3   2   1
4   4   0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html). Performance is almost the same as [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html) but `diff` seems to be faster by a a little.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': [5,6,3,2,4]})
df['column2'] = (df['column1'] <df['column1'].shift(-1)).astype(int)
print(df)
   column1  column2
0        5        1
1        6        0
2        3        0
3        2        1
4        4        0
```